# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar un contenedor sin que se pierda el espacio en donde iba?

Tags: html, css

Disculpen, estoy empezando a programar y no sé cómo hacer esto.

Yo tengo un "*contenedor padre*" el cual tiene adentro un *titulo* y un "*contenedor hijo*" (que adentro tiene otros elementos). Lo que yo quisiera hacer es ocultar ese "*contenedor hijo*", pero que el "*contenedor padre*" siga teniendo el mismo tamaño como si el "*contenedor hijo*" nunca se hubiera ocultado.

Esto lo quisiera hacer porque el "*contenedor hijo*" se despliega cuando le haces click al *título*, pero cuando el cursor deja de estar sobre el "*contenedor padre*", el "*contenedor hijo*" se esconde. Pero de la manera en lo que lo tengo, el "*contenedor padre*" cambia su tamaño dependiendo si el "*contenedor hijo*" está desplegado o no, y no es lo que quiero. Yo quisiera que el "*contenedor padre*" tuviera siempre el mismo tamaño. Pero claro, que ese tamaño siempre abarcara el "*contenedor hijo*", de modo que este no se desbordara o le quedara demasiado grande.

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo, ayuda :(

**Código HTML:**
(El "*contenedor padre*" al que me refiero es el `div` que tiene `class="contenedor"`, y el "*contenedor hijo*" es el `div` que tiene `id="cajaNegra"` )

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="background-image: url('./leyes.jpg');">
            <div id="primero" class="container-fluid contenedor text-center">
                <h1 id="titulo">Esto es una prueba</h1>
                <div id="cajaNegra" class="container text-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime incidunt a, ducimus soluta, enim eius possimus </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Más información</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="background-image: url('./asesor.jpg');">
            <div id="segundo" class="container-fluid contenedor text-center">
                <h1 id="titulo">Esto es una prueba</h1>
                <div id="cajaNegra" class="container text-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime incidunt a, ducimus soluta, enim eius possimus </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Más información</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Código SCSS:**

```
.col {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    .contenedor{
        width: auto;
        padding: 3em;
        h1 {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0.9em;
            position: relative;
            top: 0.5em;
            color: white;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        #cajaNegra{
            display: none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);
            border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.767);
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 1em 4em;
            p {
                color: white;
            }
            .btn{
                margin: 0.6em;
            }
        }
    }
     
}
```

**Código Javascript:**
(Aquí es donde hago lo del despliegue del "*contenedor hijo*")

```
//titulo:hover
$("h1").mouseenter(function(){
    var titulo = $(this).get(0);
    $(titulo).css("color", "rgb(5, 183, 196)");
    $(titulo).mouseleave(function(){
        $(titulo).css("color", "white");
    });
});

//Despliegue de la Caja Negra
$("div").click(function(){
    var contenedor = $(this).get(0);
    var titulo = $(contenedor).children('#titulo');
    var cajaNegra = $(contenedor).children('#cajaNegra');
    
    //Mostrar
    $(titulo).css("top", "0px");
    $(titulo).css("color", "rgb(5, 183, 196)");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(cajaNegra).slideDown("4000");
    }, 300);

    //Ocultar
    $(contenedor).mouseleave(function(){
        $(cajaNegra).slideUp("2000");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(cajaNegra).slideUp("2000");
            $(titulo).css("color", "white");
            $(titulo).css("top", "0.5em");
        }, 400);
        
    });
});
```

***Nota:** Ando usando Bootstrap y jQuery. Lo digo por si es pertinente saberlo*.

Comment: Prueba con `visibility: hidden;` en lugar de `display:none;`

Comment: por cierto, los CSS no son anidados tal como lo estas poniendo... asi no te van a funcionar bien... hazte algún tutorial rápido de CSS porque eso estropea todo

Comment: SI te soy sincera me equivoque ahí, porque ando escribiendo el código en SCSS, y uso un compilador aparte que transforma ese código mío en CSS (por eso me confundí). Sé que suena más trabajo hacerlo así, pero tengo mis razones

Comment: ok, pues prueba lo de la visibility a ver si sirve

Comment: Sí me sirvió, muchísimas gracias